# AJAX - Reload block from js on Drupal

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I want to reload block content from js. I have created the module with menu call back and so on, so everything works fine, when I click some link with class="use-ajax" and my module`s url. But I want to reload block content from js, without clicking the link. Please advise.

It works with link like that: `<a href="/ajax-reader/nojs/259" class="use-ajax">Reload</a>`

Comment: Did it by hiding the ling and simulating the click by $("#reloadlink").click(); ) Ugly, but works for now)

Answer (score 0):

you shoudl simply add a loop:

```
        counteriz();
            function counteriz(){
               $('.use-ajax').click();
               var timstap = setTimeout(function(){counteriz()}, 4000);
               timstap;
            }
```

but in my mind you shoudl directly load the content in the block liek this:

```
            counteriz();
            function counteriz(){
                  $('.use-ajax').stop().load('urlofyourmenucallback');
                  var timstap = setTimeout(function(){counteriz()}, 4000);
                  timstap;
            }
```